# I can call so imagePicker that the program is waiting for image selection

Tags: swift3

my delegate always returns nil for my image in custom table cell.
PhotoTakingHelper just class for imagepicker setting.
How i can pausing programm for pick image?

Method in CustomCell class:

```
@IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            loadingImage=true
            if delegate != nil {
               let (image,name) = delegate.loadImageForQuestionAction(question: question)
                 print("Delegate return \(image)")
                imageInCreatingCell = image
                nameInCreatingCell = name

                //loadImageButton.isHidden = true

            }
        }
```

Method in tableView class:

```
func loadImageForQuestionAction(question: Question) -> (UIImage?,String?) {

        var returnImage:UIImage?
        var returnName:String?

            self.photoTakingHelper=PhotoTakingHelper(viewcontroller: self, callback: { (image:UIImage?,name:String?) in
                if let photoImage = image {
                    print(photoImage)
                    print(name)
                    returnImage=photoImage
                    returnName=name

                    //NEED SHOWING IMAGE NAME HOW LABEL
                    print("loadImageAction")
                }
            })
        return (returnImage,returnName)
    }
```

Method in PhotoTakingHelper:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        //viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        categoryViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        var fileName:String? = nil
        if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
            let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil)
            fileName = result.firstObject?.value(forKey: "filename") as! String?
        }

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            callBack(image,fileName)
        } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            callBack(image,fileName)
        } else {
            print("Something went wrong")
            callBack(nil,nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
func loadImageForQuestionAction(question: Question, completion: @escaping (UIImage?, String?) -> ()) {
        var returnImage:UIImage?
        var returnName:String?

        self.photoTakingHelper=PhotoTakingHelper(viewcontroller: self, callback: { (image:UIImage?,name:String?) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let photoImage = image {
                    print(photoImage)
                    print(name)
                    returnImage=photoImage
                    returnName=name

                    completion(returnImage,returnName)
                    //NEED SHOWING IMAGE NAME HOW LABEL
                    print("loadImageAction")
                } else {
                    completion(returnImage,returnName)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: close question please